# Q-Q-Plot far off

Tags: normality-assumption, qq-plot

I used the plot command in R to check whether my data fulfills the regression assumptions. Apparently, it is not even close to a normal distribution (see Q-Q-Plot). Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Comment: These aren't data, but residuals. Tell us more about the response `leaflet`: if it is, as I guess wildly,  a 0. 1 variable then it can't be normal, nor is there an expectation that normal errors are appropriate. You would be better off thinking logit.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Yes, leaflet is binary (0,1) but my professor told me that I don't have to use a logit model and can work with a linear regression model.

Comment: Yes; but choosing a linear regression model doesn't make its assumptions hold any more than choosing a cat makes it like a dog. If the observed response is (0, 1) then two clumps of residuals are expected, positive residuals for response 1 and negative residuals for response 0.  Fortunately normal errors is the least important assumption of linear regression.